# detecting if a user is on a mobile usin javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mobile, cross-browser

I have a website that is designed in flash using swfobject, so i have a `div` named `"flashcontent"` that wraps around my site.

When javascript is enabled, the flash website is shown, i also have an alternative for when javascript is disabled or not available, in that case i see a html site, now my question is:

how can i detect when a user is using a mobile, so it uses the html site and a seperate `mobile.css` for use with the mobile version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP this might help http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

If you are using Javascript try this: http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm